# How to use DDL(Description Definition Language) of mpeg-7 to modify existing descriptor?

Tags: ddl, mpeg

In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_Definition_Language) (and in MPEG-7 standard), it says:

> DDL (Description Definition Language) is part of the MPEG-7 standard. It gives an important set of tools for the users to create their own Description Schemes (DSs) and Descriptors (Ds). DDL defines the syntax rules to define, combine, extend and modify Description Schemes and Descriptors.

But I can't found any tutorial about how to use DDL to modify existing DS or D. Any example?